# How to scan number from n-th position in C

Tags: c

Hello I might need a little help with scanning from file.
Each line contains 8 numbers long digit but i need to scan only the last four.

My idea was to scan the whole number and than from 4th position copy numbers to new array. Any smarter ideas?

Comment: Do you want four separate digits, or one number that consists of the last 4 digits?

Comment: I want only one number... 
for example the number in file is 01012000 and i want to print out only 2000

Comment: I must say while you were arguing I tried to do the method you suggested... And i simply cannot say anything bad... It worked perfectly!!! Thank you Grijesh (where is your answer btw?).

Comment: My browser did not display it at first :P. Thank to all of you. I tried different techniques and mostly it worked! :)

Comment: @Toesmash Review teppic's answer also. And if you like you can change your acceptance of answer he purposed a nice technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to read a line with `fgets` in a loop and then just run something like this:

```
sscanf(buf, "%*4d%4d", &a);
```

This will ignore the first four digits, and copy the last four digits into integer `a`.

There's obviously no error checking there (it'll only work if there are 8 digits per line), but it's quick and easy. You could check that the return of `scanf` is 1, which will be the case for a successful 4 digit number read.

**Edit** (by @Grijesh Chauhan)

Sample code:

```
int main(){
    FILE* fp = fopen("file","r");
    char buf[128];
    int a;
    while(!feof(fp)){             // while end of file comes
      fgets(buf, 127, fp);         //read complete line in a buffer 
      sscanf(buf, "%*4d%4d", &a);  //scanf from buffer, last 4 digits
      printf("%d\n",a);         
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and it executes:

```
$ gcc y.c -Wall -o y
$ ./y
5678
5432
8324
3223
```

for a file:

```
$ cat file
12345678
98765432
45678324
98653223
```

Comment: better technique then me :)

Comment: sorry Grijesh but i have to agree!! Still you all guys helped me a lot :)

Comment: @Toesmash no sorry/ no thanks is SO culture instead always vote a good answer and accept helpful answer , Teppic's answer is nice and I didn't notice initially

Answer (score 1):

Following technique in C can be useful to read a file like I have shown below, Is this what you wants?

while EOF not reach:

- first read 4 chars in first buffer, and unused
- read number in a line, using `fscanf()`, `%d`
- read `\n`
- print number

The file is like:

```
$ cat file
12345678
98765432
45678324
98653223
```

And code is (read comments):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    FILE* fp = fopen("file","r");
    char first[5];
    int second;
    while(!feof(fp)){          //  While EOF loop runs   
     fgets(first, 5, fp);      //  read first 4 chars in a line
     fscanf(fp,"%d",&second);  //  Read next 4 digits in 
     fgetc(fp);                //  read \n
     printf("%d\n",second);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

it runs like:

```
:~$ ./a.out 
5678
5432
8324
3223
```

Comment: You shouldn't return 1 from `main` on success, it's used for errors.

Comment: @teppic Yes and we should use use `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE` macros

Comment: 0 is standard enough - but EXIT_SUCCESS is a nice way to exit.

Comment: @teppic Actually main reruns process termination status that may be different for different Operation Systems, So I always prefer these macros.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Not for `0`, it always means success (and you should include `stdlib.h`).

Comment: @effeffe yes that was I mean to says its for Success it can be `0` or `1` depends on os

Answer (score 0):

On each line, read (and discard) four characters with `getc`, then use `fscanf` to read a number with 4 digits.

I would have simply passed the file through `sed` first though:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]{4}\([0-9]{4}\)$/\1/' <file | your_c_program.out
```

As a bonus, using `sed` in this way validates that each line has indeed exactly 8 digits on it.

EDIT: using `fseek` instead of `getc` is a better idea indeed

Answer (score 0):

This program read the last four numbers on each line (assuming each line has 8) and places it in the variable nr:

```
int main(void) {
char buff[8];
int nr;
FILE *theFile=fopen("/home/mppl/Desktop/file","r");

 while(fscanf(theFile,"%s\n",buff)!=EOF){
    nr= atoi(&buff[4]);
    printf("nr=%d\n",nr);

 }

}
```

This one might not be the most secure, or most efficient way of doing this but it's simple indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting question, and I am not a C expert. I just leave my solution.
 
Although I am using "getline" function in the codes below, I will vote for "sscanf".
But "sscanf" is often used for taking out particular elements from a string(like numbers divided by slash, backslash or dot), @Toesmash 's question is to read from specific position, which is nothing to do with the content. You got to consider if such a simple task is worth it.
So maybe "getline" is simple and good enough. That's my thought.

```
int main()
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    if ((fp = fopen("sample.txt", "r")) == NULL )
    {
        /* do your error process */
    }

    while((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
    {
        /* you see here offset is 5, if you want the last 4 characters */
        printf("%s", (line + (read - 5)));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The good thing is, you got everything you need, the pointer to head, the length, etc.
The bad thing is, I read the whole line, which is maybe unnecessary :)